# Error al impirmir con foreach en una vista

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Buen dia, tengo un error al querer usar el foreach en una vista.

aqui mi funcion en el controlador

```
      public function NotasPrimero()
{
    $this->primero = secmaterias::select('estado','codmat','nombmat')->get();
    $Contador = 0;
    for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) 
    {
        $value = substr($this->Codigpri, $Contador ,3);
        $Matenom = NombreMaterias($value);
        $nuevoRegistro = $this->primero->push(["codmat" => $value, "nombmat" => $Matenom]);
        $Contador = $Contador + 3;
    }
}
```

si ejecuto dd($this->primero); me arroja esto
dd($this->primero);
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la tabla sematerias esta vacia, en el for hago es sacar el codigo de cada materia que esta a la variable $this->Codigpri (es un estring donde estan los codigos, de 3 digitos, ejemplo "546898765564", la funcion NombreMaterias devuelve el nombre de la materia, y con el push lo grabo en el arreglo, ahora el problema se presenta en la vista, tengo esto

```
      @isset($primero)
          @foreach ($primero as $detalle)             
          <tr>
            <td>{{ $detalle['codmat'] }}</td>
            <td>{{ $detalle['nombmat'] }}</td>
          </tr>
          @endforeach
          @endisset
```

y al ejecutar me arroja el siguiente error

method_exists(): Argument #1 ($object_or_class) must be of type object|string, array given

les agradeceria cualquier ayuda, gracias

---

al hacer @dd($detalle) me sale esto
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: pon  `@dd($detalle)` dentro del foreach de la vista, y actualiza tu pregunta con lo que te sale

Comment: Buenas tardes, al hacer @dd($detalles) muestra el primer registro del arreglo

Answer (score 0):

Para validar en vez de @isset($primero) puedes probar con:

```
@if(!empty($primero))
@if(isset($primero))
@if($primero->isNotEmpty())
@if(count($primero) > 0)
```

Aunque sean similares en blade el proceso @if y @isset se manejan de manera diferentes puede que ahi radique tu error

Aqui estan los metodos disponibles de los objetos|arreglos tipo coleccion
https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/collections#available-methods

Comment: ya probe, la validacion esta bien, el problema se da en el foreach

Comment: intenta esto
$this->primero = collect(secmaterias::select('estado','codmat','nombmat')->get()->toArray);
Eso deberia convertir el arreglo de ellocuent collection a collection simple

Comment: Me da este error Property [toArray] does not exist on this collection instance.

Comment: Buenas tardes, ya logre solucionarlo con esta linea, $this->primero = $this->primero->toArray();